# Is RMS or MEAN appropriate for a DC current signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, statistics

I've extracted SCADA data recording (every 2 seconds) the DC current applied from a DC power supply (Sorenson SGA) during a steady state (current control mode) electrolysis trial.
To report the average applied current over the trial, should I use RMS, or is the mean appropriate? It's a pretty noisy signal (SNR of 2.4) with lots of data records (around 10k).
[image: Excel chart]

Answer (score 1):

This depends a lot on what you actually want to do with this data.

If you want to look at your clipping margin, use the peak. If you want an estimate of average and/or heat dissipation use RMS, if you are interested in biases, use the mean. If you want to track the energy storage in your supply, you need something more sophisticated.

However, in most cases RMS would be the right choice, since this is more representative of average power and associated heat dissipation.